# Rails 4 and Mongoid Polymorphic association query for inverse relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Work env:
Rails 4.1.4
mongoid 4.0.0

Below are my models:

```
class User
    field :first_name, type: String, default: ""
    field :last_name, type: String, default: ""
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :user_info, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to: :company
    has_one :user, class_name: 'User', as: :user_info, dependent: :destroy
end
```

If I try to access first_name of my employee, it returns nil even if the record exist in Mongo Document

Below in my query that results into a nil in-spite object being present:

```
@employee = @company.employees
```

Now if i get first_name of each employee, results into nil
e.g.

```
@user = User.where(user_info: @employees.first)
@employee = @employees.first.user # this return null
```

It fires below query and results in nil:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=quikchex_v2_development collection=users selector={"user_info_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53d88cbf4e696b0bc2020000')} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.3662ms
```

If I fire same query on mongo prompt i get the ouput:

```
db.users.find({user_info_id: '53d88cbf4e696b0bc2020000'})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d88cbc4e696b0bc2000000"), "first_name" : "Nikunj", "last_name" : "Thakkar", "user_info_id" : "53d88cbf4e696b0bc2020000", "user_info_type" : "Employee" }
```

But below query returns nil

```
db.users.find({user_info_id: ObjectId('53d88cbf4e696b0bc2020000')})
```

The point to notice is rails converts the user_info_id to BSON::ObjectId('53d88cbf4e696b0bc2020000') while querying, which it shouldn't

Edit: 
I tried a below native query and it returns me the employee object:

```
User.collection.find({user_info_id: '53d88cbf4e696b0bc2020000'})
```

The issue then is mongoid converts the user_info_id to BSON::ObjectId('53d88cbf4e696b0bc2020000') while querying, which it shouldn't

Comment: Did you create an mongoid issue on github? Please link if you did.